# How to handle date format in PHP

Tags: php, api, date

I am bringing in events via 3rd party API and processing them with PHP. I cannot figure out how to handle the date: `/Date(-62135568000000-0800)/`

I assumed it was an Epoch date, however when I processed it PHP was processing the date 100+ years in the future.

```
<?php
preg_match('/\d{12}-\d{4}/',$date_string, $date);
return date('U', strtotime(substr($date[0],0, 12);
?>
```

Comment: It's in milliseconds

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @John Conde I figured it out;

```
preg_match('/\d{12}-\d{4}/',$date_string, $date);
return date('U', substr($date[0],0, 12)/1000);
```